# multiple arrays foreach loop mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have this :

```
foreach($textnode as $key => $value) {

$value = stripslashes($value);
 $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value, $con);


 mysql_query("INSERT INTO paragraphs (textnodes, url)
 VALUES ('$value', '$url')");



}
```

My table has three columns (textnodes, ytext, and url)

textnode and ytext are both arrays.....can I do this for two arrays?

Comment: What do you mean, for two arrays?

Comment: I wanted to know how can add the values from the textnode array and the ytext array into their respective rows..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is to use a normal for loop instead:

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($textnode);$i++){

    $textnode[$i] = stripslashes($textnode[$i]);
    $textnode[$i] = mysql_real_escape_string($textnode[$i], $con);

    $ytext[$i]    = stripslashes($ytext[$i]);
    $ytext[$i]    = mysql_real_escape_string($ytext[$i], $con);

     mysql_query("INSERT INTO paragraphs (paragraphs, ytext, url)
     VALUES ('$textnode[$i]', '$ytext[$i]', '$url')");

}
```

That way you can loop through both at once (not 100% sure that's what you were asking, but it's my best guess).

---

I haven't tested the code above but it should work. However the style it follows and the style you've shown above isn't very good. Here are a few improvements that could be made:

1. Instead of making a separate query for each insert, do all the inserts in one query. This is better because there is only overhead for 1 query instead of $i queries.
2. Abstract away the DB. Currently it seems that you are mixing business logic with DB logic. I can see this because you are escaping strings of text with specific purposes (textnode and ytext and url) and inserting them with a mysql query. Instead it would be prudent to abstract away the query so that the business logic isn't coupled with the db logic.
3. A smaller note - you shouldn't have to call stripslashes. If you are using magic quotes, disable it immediately instead, as it is deprecated and is considered a bad practice now.

Comment: Your SQL query can't work since you did not escaped+concatenated your variables. Make it `VALUES ('".$textnodes[$i]."', ...`

Comment: @caffein: It might not work as I haven't tested it, but that part should be fine. Read this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: No, that works. Variables in double quotes do not need to be escaped.

Comment: By the way it's not a best way to insert multiple rows to database. Imagine there are 1 mln rows in input arrays - you requsts will overload server. It's better to combine your inserts into one INSERT command: `$inserts [] = "('val1', 'val2', 'val3)";` and then finally execute all at once: `mysql_query( "INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES " . join(',', $inserts))`

Comment: @WASD42: I definitely agree - the overhead from multiple inserts would definitely put a lot of stress on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)?
It converts your array into a "storable" form (string). When you select from your table again `unserialize` will convert the string back into an array.

Just guessing, your question is somewhat unclear ...